# objc_msgSend crash Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, appkit

I got crash report from live user 
I have NSObject which has nsstring

```
@interface MountedVolume : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

View controller has textfield it values gets changed when notification 
received .

```
@interface ViewController : NSViewController {

      MountedVolume *selectedVolume;

    __weak IBOutlet NSTextField *txtVolumeName;

}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:DCNotificationNameVolumesUpdated object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//crash report says in this line it got crashed

            txtVolumeName.stringValue = selectedVolume.name;

        });
    }];


}

@end
```

Below is the crash report any suggestion how to deal with this?

crash report

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x7fff6ac2639d objc_msgSend + 29
1  AppKit                         0x7fff3db3d868 -[NSCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:] + 157
2  AppKit                         0x7fff3db3d71d -[NSCell setStringValue:] + 40
3  AppKit                         0x7fff3db95044 -[NSControl setStringValue:] + 135
4  MyApp               0x104de865b __40-[ViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_3 (ViewController.m:172)
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6c3ab5f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6c3ac63d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6c3b768d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1135
8  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff40435f56 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
9  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff40435683 __CFRunLoopRun + 2300
10 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff40434b35 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 459
11 HIToolbox                      0x7fff3f71396b RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
12 HIToolbox                      0x7fff3f7136a5 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 603
13 HIToolbox                      0x7fff3f713436 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
14 AppKit                         0x7fff3daad987 _DPSNextEvent + 965
15 AppKit                         0x7fff3daac71f -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
16 AppKit                         0x7fff3daa683c -[NSApplication run] + 699
17 AppKit                         0x7fff3da95d7c NSApplicationMain + 777
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x7fff6c3f93d5 start + 1
```

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `selectedVolume.name` doesn't change, before the block is executed in the main loop?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Looking at the docs, [stringValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428950-stringvalue) does not appear to be optional. You do not initialize selectedVolume before viewDidLoad (as far as I can tell) and that means you are likely trying to set this value to nil inside this notification block if it runs before selectedVolume is assigned a value. I would start by trying to set txtVolumeName.stringValue to a hard-coded value first and see if it stops crashing altogether. If it does, you may need to guard against nil values before you call the setter.

e.g.

```
NSString *string;
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc]init];
if (string) {
    textField.stringValue = string;
}
```